# AngularJs: How to avoid lettercase while filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

**THE SITUATION:**

I had to make my own filter, instead of using the normal angular filter, because of a particular situation:

I have a nested object on four levels: Programs - Days - Halls - Presentations.
Each hall is an accordion containing the relative presentations.

Anyway the filter i made is working properly.

Except one thing: right now the filter is letter case.

So if a presentation name is 'Automation' and the user type 'automation' it won't show up in the results.

**THE CODE:**

Right now is looking for a simple indexOf of the string entered by the user inside the presentation name:

```
angular.forEach(value_halls.presentations, function(presentation_info, key_presentation) 
{
    var name    = presentation.name;
    var index   = name.indexOf($rootScope.filter.name);

    if (index > -1 ) 
    {           
        $rootScope.program_list_filtered.push(presentation_info);
    }

});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Do you know how can i avoid letter case while filtering?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toLowerCase` on both strings:

`var index = name.toLowerCase().indexOf($rootScope.filter.name.toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is to use transform both String to Upper Case like that :

```
var name    = presentation.name.toUpperCase();
var index   = name.indexOf($rootScope.filter.name.toUpperCase());
```

Another way is to use a Regex

```
var name    = presentation.name;
var index = name.match(new RegExp($rootScope.filter.name, "i"));
```